ArcGIS Pro editing tool divide only allows for 50 graduations of a line segment?
I have an 2,047 foot line in a WaSPN(ft) CRS.  I want to divide this line into 30 foot segments.  I am trying to use the Divide option in the Modify Features Tools pane.  The tool only allows for no more than 50 repetitions as shown below but I need 68 divisions.
I see BUG-000162145 Split, Divide, and Clip give unexpected results or fail when the target layer is projected on the fly for v3.1 and v3.2 but I am using v3.3.  The data share the same CRS as the layout so this does not seem relevant.
I suppose I could create vertices along this line and split the line but this would result in more data files and not address a simple editing task.  I suppose I could accept the edits and reedit/divide the remainder but this would not address a simple editing task.
Is there something I am missing here or is this a bug in the software?

